# Using nested loops without messing up buffer location in stdin

Tags: c, nested-loops

```
while (1) {
    palindrome = my_string_init_default();
    while (1) {
        ch = getc(stdin);

        if (ch == '\n') {

            break;
        }
        else {

            continue; 
        }

        palindrome->push_back(palindrome, ch);


    }

    if (is_palindrome(palindrome)) {

        printf("Yes \n");

    }
    else {
        printf("No \n");
    }


    palindrome->destroy(&palindrome);



}

return 0;
}
```

Am trying to basically check if  a text is a palindrome or not. that part of the code isn't shown here and works perfectly fine. what am trying to do is that I read in input until there is an end of line. and then consider that line a string that I check if its a palindrome or not. but instead of ending the program there I have to go to the next line and keep on iterating until i reach EOF. how do I do that here without messing up my buffer location. Can I use fseek here?.

Comment: I don't see why you need to do anything special with respect to managing `stdin`.  (Your problem appears to have nothing to do with that.)

Comment: Is there any reason that you cannot use `scanf` ?  (i.e. read a `string` from the console (`stdin`) once instead of reading a series of `char`)

Answer (score 1):

You never reach `palindrome->push_back(palindrome, ch);` (because either break or skip to the next iteration).

Use this:

```
while (1) {
    ch = getc(stdin);
    if (ch == '\n') {
        break;
    }
    // otherwise:
    palindrome->push_back(palindrome, ch);
}
```

Update. As far as I understand what you need, you can do this (assuming that each line, even the last one, ends with `\n`, as it's ought to be in UNIX):

```
while (1) {
    palindrome = my_string_init_default();
    while (1) {
        ch = getc(stdin);

        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        palindrome->push_back(palindrome, ch);
    }

    if (ch != EOF) {
        if (is_palindrome(palindrome)) {
            printf("Yes \n");
        }
        else {
            printf("No \n");
        }
    }

    palindrome->destroy(&palindrome);

    if (ch == EOF) {
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes that was my initial code (and it works) and what i shown above is a failed attempt at making it work for more than just a single line of text. that only works for a single line. and then it ends the program.

Comment: @Byte_Spike, I do not believe you.  The outer loop of the code you present above is infinite.  Modifying it as this answer suggests will not change that.

Comment: each line seperately. basically If I insert 4 lines with a \n at end of each. it runs every line and it outputs the result after each line. I have done something similar with Case and not loops and was easier but I don't have the luxury of using Case this time.


also. again I have made it work for a single line and that isn't hard at all if I didn't i wouldn't be able to know if the palindrome code works or not .

to get what you have shown done is very simple compared to the back end data structure and the palindrome program that I had to write. this isn't really an investigation.

Comment: @Byte_Spike \*unless one of your palindrome functions or methods throws an exception, in which case those do *not* "work perfectly fine" as you asserted.

Comment: again I know what I posted was wrong but as I said that is a failed attempt at making it read more than 1 line before the program ends. the first part is trivial. thats why I mentioned that fseek might come into help because after (I successfully) was able to read in 1 line and find out if its a palindrome or not. after I read in the next line to check if its EOF. the stdin gets out of sync an it messes up the results for the following lines.